# TIdUDPClient broadcasts wrong data

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-xe4

I am sending and receiving messages from an electronic board through UDP using Delphi 6 and Indy 8. But since updating to Delphi XE4, the `TIdUDPClient` component sends wrong data packets.  I think the problem is with the `Send()` function only sends in Unicode. Is it possible to send `AnsiString` through `TIdUDPClient.Send()`?

Here is the code I am using:

```
idudpclient1.Send(#$7e#$b8#$c7#$81#$10#$8d#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$9d#$02#$0d);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending binary data as a `String`.  In XE4, Strings are Unicode, and Indy's default encoding is ASCII.  Your `String` data contains characters that are outside of the ASCII range.

Don't use `String` for binary data.  That is not what it is meant for.  You can get away with that in Delphi 2007 an earlier, but not in Delphi 2009 and later.

You can either:

1. continue using `Send()`, but tell it to use Indy's 8bit encoding instead of Indy's default encoding:

   ```
   IdUDPClient1.Send(#$7e#$b8#$c7#$81#$10#$8d#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$00#$9d#$02#$0d, Indy8BitEncoding);
   ```
2. switch to `SendBuffer()` instead (which you should do, even in your Indy 8 code):

   ```
   var
     Buf: TIdBytes;
   begin
     SetLength(Buf, 34);
     FillBytes(Buf, 34, $00);
     Buf[0] := $7e;
     Buf[1] := $b8;
     Buf[2] := $c7;
     Buf[3] := $81;
     Buf[4] := $10;
     Buf[5] := $8d;
     Buf[31] := $9d;
     Buf[32] := $02;
     Buf[33] := $0d;
     IdUDPClient1.Send(Buf);
   end;
   ```